# can I open the pdf in current or new tab from html2pdf instead of downloading it (open pop up )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2pdf

Hi so I created a function using html2pdf, it works fine pdf is generated and can download it with no problem, but now I want the function to open the file directly instead of opening the browser pop up to open/save file

function looks like this:

```
const download = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById("element-to-print");
    const opt = {
      filename: patientName + "_Report.pdf",
      image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
      jsPDF: { unit: "in", format: "a4", orientation: "landscape" },
    };

    // New Promise-based usage:
    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
   
  };

 
    }, []);
```

Comment: If you search SO you'll find hundreds of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+pdf+open) that might help.  How to open a pdf is probably the second most asked JavaScript question.

Comment: the main problem is that this functionality is going to be used in a PWA app. That's why I need it to open directly in the pdf view instead of downloading it.

Comment: Basically I need for the pop up (download or open with ) not to show at all and the user not to have the option to download it by default

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.save()` which will open the default pop-up to download or open
use `.output('dataurlnewwindow')` option from `jspdf` witch opens the pdf in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

you can load the PDF generated in a new tab:

```
html2pdf().from(element).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
  window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
});
```